# Angular - change objects to array and make it listen to on change

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, angular-components

This problem is very basic, I know, but I need help in the following situation.
First I want to use the balance value of the Fix interface in a single array, to add it to the chart.js data and the name value to the label.

I've built the interface and a component.

You can see (and I see you smashing your heads against the wall) that I did a for loop in two single lines (`labels: ....` and `data: ....`)that shows what I expect.

```
export interface Fix {
  name?: String,
  balance?: number
}

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { Fix } from '../fix';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-container',
  templateUrl: './container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./container.component.scss']
})
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  public chart: Chart;
  public fix: Fix[];

  constructor() {

    this.fix = [
      {'name': 'Fix1', 'balance': 123},
      {'name': 'Fix2', 'balance': 23}
    ]

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chart = new Chart('chart', {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: [for (let bal of this.fix) {bal.name}],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [for (let bal of this.fix) {bal.balance}]
            }]
        }
    });
  }

}
```

I know I could run a loop like

```
for (let x if this.fix) {
    labelsArray.push(x.name);
    fixArray.push(x.balance);
}
```

and use this for my chart.js but this brings me to the next point.
Later instead of defining fix in the constructor, the object will be outputted from a child component. Every time the values change, the chart should be updated.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: 1, how can I turn `[{'name': 'Fix1', 'balance': 123}, {'name': 'Fix2', 'balance': 23}]` into `[123, 23]` and `['Fix1', 'Fix2']` to use it for my chart and 2. how can I update the chart when `fix`changes?

Comment: 1.-Use map to create an array with only one propertie: `labels:this.fix.map(x=>x.name);data:this.fix.map(x=>x.balance)`. 2.-create a function that you call in ngInit and call when the data change

Comment: 1. is working thank you. 2. can you be more specific? I don't understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I follow you 100% but here is what I can see you asking for:

```
// return only the id values in your objects
console.log(this.fix.map(x=>x.id));
```

In order to force updates in a child component I do this:

**ParentComponent View**

```
<child-component [fix]="childFixArray"></child-component>
```

**ChildComponent Controller**

```
// This property is bound using its original name.
@Input('childFixArray') fix: [];

// sometimes updates will not occur fi ANgular is not triggered to update the DOM. 
// Use ngOnChanges in the child to monitor for updates
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if ('fix' in changes) {
        // console.log(this.fix);
    }
    this.doSomething(changes.fix.currentValue);
    this.doSomething(changes.fix.previousValue);
    this.doSomething(changes.fix.firstChange);
}
```